# How to create perform action when swipe recycler view item. Just like swipe to delete option in gmail app. But recycler view item should not removed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe-gesture, recyclerview-layout

**when swipe recycler view item it goes to edge to display and come back to original view. Just like textra sms app and true caller app. When swipe it should trigger a action. This is something like swipe delete. But swipe delete action trigger after completely removed from the view. In my situation recycler view item not remove.**

Also I search libraries. But i cant found anything. Any one can help me to create that?

i post example gif in the below

[image]

Comment: Can you rewrite your question? It is not clear to me. You want to show a delete button on swipe, right?

Comment: Did you try to use "search" option? You can found many solutions like: https://codeburst.io/android-swipe-menu-with-recyclerview-8f28a235ff28  or https://medium.com/@kitek/recyclerview-swipe-to-delete-easier-than-you-thought-cff67ff5e5f6

Answer (score 0):

What you want to be using is a [ItemTouchHelper.Callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ItemTouchHelper.Callback)

here's a very niceley written tutorial on exactly your needs:

https://codeburst.io/android-swipe-menu-with-recyclerview-8f28a235ff28

Example:

[image]